# What does upgrading the Spike-O-Pult with Triple Shot actually do?

Tags: bloons-td-4

I'm having trouble figuring out if the triple spike is worth it or not, because I'm not sure what it does.

Does upgrading it with Triple Shot increase the fire rate? Does it make the shot bigger? Or something else?